# Responsive server side rendering with React

Tags: responsive-design, reactjs, server-side

I would like to be able to render a different layout based on the device's width.

(i.e. show a picture to the left of an element when the device is small and on top when the device is large).

It would be possible of course on client via matchMedia, but I'm using server side rendering on would like to preserve the rendering consistency.

The best I could come up with is using MobileDetect and assume the device's width (basically, if it's a phone...), but it's still an assumption.

Are there any better methods?

Comment: Of course there are better methods. Why solve positioning on server side when you can use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)? Imagine user opening your page in a small window, then he maximizes it. He'll see improperly rendered page and will have to reload it. Doesn't sound convenient.

Comment: This path you're on is not a good idea at all. @kecers suggestion is _the_ way to do responsive web.

Comment: I am using css media queries extensively. But in this case the layout is substantially different... Another solution I could use is render the picture twice in two different places and hide one of them according to the media query.

But that doesn't seem so good either...

Comment: If you want to handle mobile devices differently, why not redirect them to a subdomain or slightly different endpoint, where you'll always render the modified layout? That should save you and the users a headache using the app

Comment: This is certainly one way to go, I've been able to create about 80% of the website so far with one layout with very minor changes for mobile devices. A responsive grid and thinking does most of the work. By the way, redirecting to a subdomain is quite similar to using MobileDetect and changing the layout based on the useragent, which I've mentioned in my question.